# how do i reset a random choice selection in a game using python

Tags: python

please i am learning to code an adventure game using python. i"m comfortable with the way the code runs, only that when the player chooses to play game again it repeats the same old choice of creature. i want it to make a new selection of creature whenever the player chooses to play game again and maintain the choice till the end of the round. here is my code:

```
import random
import time

creatures = ["wicked fairy","gorilla","huge beast","maskquarade","Giant"]

def get_random_creature():
    creature = random.choice(creatures)
    return creature


creature = get_random_creature()


def print_pause(str):
    print(str)
    time.sleep(2)


def print_pause_longer(str1,str2,str3):
    print(str1,str2,str3)
    time.sleep(3)

def intro():
    print_pause("You find yourself standing in an open field")
    print_pause_longer("Rumour has it that a",creature,"is somewhere around here,")
    print_pause("it has been terrorizing a nearby village")
    print_pause("In front of you are two passage ways.")
    print_pause("Left and Right")
    print_pause("Enter 'L' to go left")
    print_pause("Enter 'R' to go right")


def go_left():
    print_pause("You take left, and find an old cave")
    print_pause("What would you like to do?")
    print_pause("Enter 1 to get into the cave")
    print_pause("Enter 2 to go back to the open field")
    choice2 = input()
    if choice2 == "1":
        in_cave()
    elif choice2 =="2":
       open_field()
    else:
        go_left()

def in_cave():
    print_pause("You push open the door of cave")
    print_pause("The first thing you saw was a shinny sword that spinned around on its own")
    print_pause("what would you like to do next?")
    print_pause("Enter 1 to collect the sword")
    print_pause("Enter 2 to leave the cave")
    choice3 =input()
    if choice3 == "1":
        collect_sword()
    elif choice3 == "2":
        leave_cave()
    else:
        in_cave()


def collect_sword():
    print_pause("You reach out for the sword and collect it")
    print_pause("Then you walk out of the cave")
    print_pause("As you moved some miles from the cave")
    print_pause("You heared a loud noise")
    print_pause_longer("Sounds like the",creature,"grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrh!!!")
    print_pause("It is right behind you")
    print_pause("what would you do next?")
    print_pause("Enter 1 to run away")
    print_pause("Enter 2 to fight")
    choice4 = input()
    if choice4 == "1":
        run_away()
    elif choice4 == "2":
        win_fight()
    else:
        collect_sword()


def run_away():
    print_pause("You make an attempt to run away")
    print_pause_longer("The",creature, "catches up with you")
    print_pause("You are defeated")
    play_again()


def win_fight():
    print_pause("You turn around to fight")
    print_pause_longer("As the ",creature, "beheld your shinny sword, it fell dead")
    print_pause_longer("You have rid the town of the",creature,"Yay!!")
    print_pause("You are Victorious")
    play_again()


def lost_fight():
    print_pause_longer("You face the ", creature," with courage")
    print_pause("But in no time")
    print_pause("You discovered you've just engaged in a lost battle")
    print_pause("You have been defeated")
    play_again()


def leave_cave():
    print_pause("You leave the cave")
    print_pause("You take right, and find a house")
    print_pause("You pushed the door open to get in")
    print_pause_longer("AHHHH!!!", "it is the house of the", creature)
    print_pause("You were Terrified")
    print_pause("Enter 1 to run away")
    print_pause("Enter 2 to fight back")
    choice5 = input()
    if choice5 == "1":
        run_away()
    elif choice5 == "2":
        lost_fight()
    else:
        leave_cave()


def open_field():
    print_pause("You hurry back to the open field")
    print_pause("In front of you are two passage ways.")
    print_pause("Left and Right")
    print_pause("Enter 'L' to go left")
    print_pause("Enter 'R' to go right")
    play_game()


def go_right():
    print_pause("You take right, and find a house")
    print_pause("You pushed the door open to get in")
    print_pause_longer("AHHHH!!!", "it is the house of the", creature)
    print_pause("You were Terrified")
    print_pause("Enter 1 to run away")
    print_pause("Enter 2 to fight back")
    choice6 = input()
    if choice6 == "1":
        run_away()
    elif choice6 == "2":
        lost_fight()
    else:
        go_right()

def play_game():
    choice1 = input()
    if choice1 == "L":
        go_left()
    elif choice1 == "R":
        go_right()
    else:
        print_pause("Sorry,i don't get you")
        intro()
        play_game()


def play_again():
    print_pause("Would you like to play again, yes or no")
    play_again = input("y or n\n")
    if play_again == "n":
        print_pause("Thanks for playing! See you next time.")
    elif play_again == "y":
        print_pause("Excellent! Restarting the game...")
        intro()
        play_game()
    else:
        play_again()


intro()
play_game()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `get_random_creature()` is called only once at the biggining in `creature = get_random_creature()`. 
You `intro()` function uses the same `creature` variable (already stored) every time you call it

You can easily fix this by adding `creature = get_random_creature()` into your intro function:

```
def intro():
    creature = get_random_creature()
    print_pause("You find yourself standing in an open field")
    print_pause_longer("Rumour has it that a",creature,"is somewhere around here,")
    print_pause("it has been terrorizing a nearby village")
    print_pause("In front of you are two passage ways.")
    print_pause("Left and Right")
    print_pause("Enter 'L' to go left")
    print_pause("Enter 'R' to go right")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You also need to add it as a parameter to all the function definitions that use the creature name, otherwise it will only be available in the intro's function context. Or you could declare it as None at the start then change it in intro.

Comment: You are right @BoboDarph. Didn't look too deep into the code and missed that :(

Comment: Your code would have worked anyway, because if he keeps it in the main and in the intro function as random, it's still in the context. If he just moved it from the main to the intro, it would have crapped out because context. It would be an interesting time debugging it tho if he declares it random in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Ary's answer, I would declare the creature variable as None at the start of the game, then populate it with a random value in the intro() function.

example below:

```
creature = None


def print_pause(str):
    print(str)
    time.sleep(0.1)


def print_pause_longer(str1,str2,str3):
    print(str1,str2,str3)
    time.sleep(0.1)

def intro():
    creature = get_random_creature()
    print_pause("You find yourself standing in an open field")
    print_pause_longer("Rumour has it that a",creature,"is somewhere around here,")
    print_pause("it has been terrorizing a nearby village")
    print_pause("In front of you are two passage ways.")
    print_pause("Left and Right")
    print_pause("Enter 'L' to go left")
    print_pause("Enter 'R' to go right")
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but it didnt work. rather,a new creature gets called each time the variable "creature" is mentioned in  the code. the plan is to pick a creature at random and maintain its value through the game round until the player selects the play again option, then there should be another random pick